# Is there a way to translate HibernateException to something else, then DataAccessException in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make more sense out of constraint violation errors, happening during transaction persistence in Hibernate.

The only way I see how to interfere with HibernateExceptions is through PersistenceExceptionTranslator in spring,

```
package org.springframework.dao.support;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public interface PersistenceExceptionTranslator {

    DataAccessException translateExceptionIfPossible(RuntimeException ex);

}
```

which translates Hibernate exceptions to DataAccessExceptions, but that means I'll need to inherit my exception hierarchy from DataAccessExceptions.

***Is there any other natural way to do this, without introducing DataAceessExceptions in Exception inheritance hierarchy?***

Answer (score 1):

You can catch `HibernateException` and rethrow it as a **checked exception** from your repository method. But then you will have to deal with the exception in the upper layers, but you also can simply keep throwing it outside your code layer.

Comment: Not too eligant, PersistenceExceptionTranslator is much nicer :)

Comment: I know, but you asked for different solution, so i brought you one :) Besides that, you won't have to extend `DataAccessException`

Comment: Maybe you want to use `@ExceptionHandler`? See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: Why not elegant ? You could catch HibernateException in your dao methods and re-throw. Sounds quite reasonable to me