# Spring MVC handling exceptions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've built a spring mvc application using the **controller->service->dao** architecture. The DAO objects are using hibernate. The services are annotated `@Transactional`.

I'm trying to catch dao exceptions in the service, wrap them up and then throw them to my controller:

Service

```
@Override
public Entity createEntity(Entity ent) throws ServiceException {
    try {
        return entityDAO.createEntity(ent);
    } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
        LOG.error("Unable to create entity", dae);
        throw new ServiceException("We were unable to create the entity for the moment. Please try again later.", dae);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createEntity(@ModelAttribute(value = "newEntity") Entity newEntity, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        try {
            entityService.createEntity(newEntity);
        } catch (ServiceException se) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", se.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return "redirect:/entity/manage";
}
```

However, even though the DataAccessException is caught at the service level, it keeps bubbling up to my controller somehow.

If for example I don't meet a unique field criteria on the database level I get an HTTP Error 500 with the following:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.garmin.pto.domain.Entity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477054/org-hibernate-assertionfailure

Answer (score 0):

Code is caching DataAccessException not HibernateException, try caching HibernateException

[Is there a way to translate HibernateException to something else, then DataAccessException in sping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564522/is-there-a-way-to-translate-hibernateexception-to-something-else-then-dataacces)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the exception in the Controller, don't catch it in the Service.

Service

```
@Override
public Entity createEntity(Entity ent) throws DataAccessException {
    return entityDAO.createEntity(ent);
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createEntity(@ModelAttribute(value = "newEntity") Entity newEntity, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    try {
        entityService.createEntity(newEntity);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
    }
    return "redirect:/entity/manage";
}
```

Or if you want to leverage Spring the handle the exception, use ExceptionHandler annotation. You can find good tutorial online, for example, [Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/).

Answer (score 0):

To make exception translation working

1. You have to annotate your DAO with @Repository
2. Make sure you have declared this bean `<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) is a beautiful post on different ways to handle exceptions on a Spring MVC project.

Among those, I find using `@ControllerAdvice` classes, to handle all the exceptions at one place globally, the most convenient in general. [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon)'s source code could serve as a good concrete example.